# Store multiple values in localStorage when clicked on

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

So what im trying to do is have jQuery remember what was clicked on.

So say the user clicks on a list item and also clicks on another list item. How would i store both item classes that the user clicked on.

Here is what i have currently

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#terms-product_cat ul li').on('click', function(event) {
        $(this).addClass('current-term');
        window.localStorage['temp_type'] = $(this).find('label').attr('class');
    });
    alert(window.localStorage['temp_type']);
});
```

Comment: you want to store these values in a variable?

Comment: please submit your HTML code also

Comment: Just as a suggestion, use the methods that `localStorage` provides: `.getItem("key")` and `.setItem("key", "value")`

Comment: HEre is a JSfiddle, I cannot use the checkboxes, only list item clicks.

http://jsfiddle.net/hZNLg/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#terms-product_cat ul li').on('click', function(event) {
    $(this).addClass('current-term');
    var maybe_string = window.localStorage['temp_type'];
    var array = maybe_string ? JSON.parse(maybe_string) : [];
    array.push($(this).find('label').attr('class'));
    window.localStorage['temp_type'] = JSON.stringify(array);
});
```

Comment: You're sure you can store arrays in localstorage, and that they are not converted to strings.

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character
 

var array = JSON.parse(window.localStorage['temp_type']) || [];